# Exception while deploying webapplication in tomcat 8 - Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager'

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator, beancreationexception

#### Using Spring '3.0.5.RELEASE' and hibernate hibernate-core version '3.5.6-Final' and deployed on Tomcat 8.0.18

Spring XML configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/xxx-security-persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xxx-security-pu-456" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I have the below exception in the logs:

```
    17-Jun-2016 13:00:00.231 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.xxx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xxx.xxContextListener
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [spring_context_security_service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring_context_security_service_stack_mint.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at com.xx.xx.x.x.x.x.SecuritySpringContextLoader.initialzed(SecuritySpringContextLoader.java:31)
        at com.x.x.x.x.server.context.AuthnWebContextListener.contextInitialized(AuthnWebContextListener.java:24)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring_context_security_service_stack_mint.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:477)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyConstraintsToDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:429)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:403)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1459)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1086)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:685)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:95)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:83)
        ... 54 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validation
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 56 more

    17-Jun-2016 13:00:07.072 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    17-Jun-2016 13:00:07.073 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Some more logs in localhost.log

```
    12:59:59.983 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: xx-security-pu-456
            persistence provider classname: null
            classloader: WebappClassLoader^M
      context: authnweb^M
      delegate: false^M
    ----------> Parent Classloader:^M
    java.net.URLClassLoader@404b9385^M

            Temporary classloader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@5cf3ac57
            excludeUnlistedClasses: false
            JTA datasource: null
            Non JTA datasource: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@689d1794
            Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
            PU root URL: file:/Users/xx/Downloads/softwares/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/authnweb/WEB-INF/lib/security-common-0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
            Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
            Validation Mode: AUTO
```

Comment: Just Google this "Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory" - there are plenty of people getting this. The solution appears to be the removal of a validation-api jar

Comment: also did you see the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validation" error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you somehow explicitly enabled Bean Validation. Either disable this or add Hibernate Validator and Bean Validation API to your POM.